# Collector-Emitter short but not Base-Emitter

Tags: transistors, junction

I have a power amp that blew the pair of transistors(2SD1047 and 2SB817) at the output. The positive side 1047 is totally shorted, all junctions, the negative side 817 is only shorted Collector-Emitter. My question is how can that junction short without affecting the Base-Emitter junction?

Answer (score 1):

Once things start melting inside any device it can end up in many states, including the bonding wires melting and shorting together.

If you have enough current on failure, things usually burn out leaving them open, but that depends on the rest of your circuitry and what other failures cascade out of the initial failure.